# Can addition and subtraction be written as the product of prime factors

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Is there a way, in general, to write $a-b$ or $a+b$ in the form $2^{n_{1}} \cdot 3^{n_{2}} \cdot 5^{n_{3}} \cdots$ where $n_{i}$ is the exponent on the $i$th prime?

Edit for clarification: I mean, as was pointed out in the comments, how can we write the *the result* of this operation. Meaning for $a=2^{n_{1}} \cdot 3^{n_{2}} \cdot 5^{n_{3}} \cdots$ and $b=2^{m_{1}} \cdot 3^{m_{2}} \cdot 5^{m_{3}} \cdots$ is there a nice formula of the form $a\pm b=2^{p_{1}} \cdot 3^{p_{2}} \cdot 5^{p_{3}} \cdots$

Comment: Of course; that's the fundamental theorem of arithmetic. It applies to all positive integers.

Comment: You mean: can *the result of* addition and subtraction be?

Comment: Are you looking for an algorithm that computes $a+b$ (or $a-b$) starting from the prime factorizations of $a$ and $b$, without converting those factorizations into base-$b$ numerals?

Comment: If $a=p$ is prime and $b=2$, we don't even know if  $a+b$ can be prime infinitely many times, let alone know its prime factorisation.

Comment: For a given prime $p$, the best we can say is that if $p^v$ divides $a$ and $p^w$ divides $b$ then $p^{\min\{v,w\}}$ divides $a\pm b$. Addition and multiplication in number theory are notorious for not cooperating publicly - see Goldbach's conjecture, the Twin Prime conjecture, and countless other open problems whose nonresolved status is due to (or at least is an illustration of) this issue.

Comment: @NickCalabrese I believe a good example of the difficulty of predicting the prime factors of the summation of $2$ integers is the [$abc$ conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abc_conjecture).

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly a nice formula, but in subtraction the necessary condition is that $a$ and $b$ are congruent mod any divisor. In the case of addition, we have them congruent additive inverses mod divisors. This isn't exactly easy to use in most cases.  A difference of squares with difference greater than 1 in the bases,  has at least 2 nontrivial factors, but it won't guarantee a full factorization.